# MySql Query for selecting column by the days of the week

Tags: mysql

I Have Following Table Structure

```
ID     IS_SUNDAY        IS_MONDAY         REST DAys..

11    Boolean value     Boolean value     Boolean value    

12    Boolean value     Boolean value     Boolean value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next query will allow you to select column for the current day of week:

```
SELECT 
  CASE DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)
    WHEN 1 THEN IS_SUNDAY
    WHEN 2 THEN IS_MONDAY
    WHEN 3 THEN IS_TUESDAY
    WHEN 4 THEN IS_WEDNESDAY
    WHEN 5 THEN IS_THURSDAY
    WHEN 6 THEN IS_FRIDAY
    WHEN 7 THEN IS_SATURDAY
  END CURRENT_DAY_OF_WEK
FROM DAYS_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IS_SUNDAY FROM yourTable WHERE ID = 11
```

But I recommend you read a good tutorial or a book before asking such simple questions.

Comment: @downvoter care to explain why? The comment in my answer may be a bit rude, still it's the truth. I mean, come on, a simple select. But yeah, sure, support this behaviour of users. By just asking, not learning, not trying to understand, they'll never get good at it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use to get the column name

```
SELECT  COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME like '%columnname%' AND TABLE_NAME='table_name';
```